# How do you call Unity to distinguish it from Unity 2D?

Tags: unity

If I've mentioned Unity 2D in a sentence and now I would like to mention Unity and distinguish it so that it will be clear that I'm talking about Unity (the accelerated one) and not Unity 2D, how should I call Unity?

"Unity 3D" is just wrong.

Comment: Hmm this questions is answered somewhere else
may be duplicate :)

Comment: How is Unity 3D wrong? it uses 3D hardware acceleration, so please explain yourself? how is it wrong to call it Unity 3D.

Comment: Unity doesn't use 3D hardware acceleration. Compiz uses that. And Unity doesn't have any 3D effects for now. And it was never intended to be called Unity 3D. And if I was the author of Unity I would not like 3D or anything added to it's name because that's not what I named it :) .

Comment: @UriHerrera Unity 3D is also the name of a popular game engine so it can conflict with that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity3D is not wrong, its commonly used to distinguish Unity from Unity2D.

But Unity is the official name of the desktop session and Unity2D is the official name for the non composed desktop session, that should be enough to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually just 'Unity'.  As long as you specifically call out Unity 2D, I don't think you need to specify Unity as being accelerated

Answer (score 0):

I agree that calling it Unity 3D might be confusing. To differentiate it, you might call it something like Unity/Compiz, or Unity (Compiz).